# Is Hudson a mature continuous integration tool now?

Tags: continuous-integration

I have searched the SO site for question about Hudson but some of it are a little dated now say 2 years or more.  Some comments link Hudson as 'newbie' ing the CI Field

I just would like to know if Hudson is mature right now and is the best option for a CI tool.

Thanks

P.S. I just would like to hear latest feedback from community.

Comment: look for http://jenkins-ci.org/ -- that's how the most popular fork of Hudson is now called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would thoroughly recommend [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), which is a fork of Hudson made in late 2010/early 2011 (wikipedia has [more information on the split](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%28software%29) if you're interested). You'll find more contemporary resources if you do a search for Jenkins - but at the moment most Hudson tutorials are still relevant.

As to stability/maturity, we've been using it for many months without any issues that I'd attribute to maturity :)

Answer (score 1):

We are using [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) for our continuous integration and found it quite useful.
All the basics are there, regarding starting builds, getting and generating statistics from i.e. build results, unit tests, function tests. It is also very flexible as you can ask Jenkins to execute a script which does pretty much anything you need.

Jenkins is the best I've tested so far, and also it is free.

Answer (score 0):

I think nobody can answer if it is the best option *for you*. It might be mature and everything, but that doesn't mean it's the best for your particular problem